# Finding a value of one key in an array based off the value of another key

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Suppose I have an object array like this:

```
var myArray = [
     {"sandwich": "hamburger", "cheese": "cheddar" },
     {"sandwich": "club", "cheese": "provolone" },
     {"sandwich": "reuben", "cheese": "swiss" }
]
```

Now, I have a variable:

```
 var sammy = "club"
```

In `myArray` I want to search for the item where "sandwich" is equal to the value of variable `sammy` and return the cheese: "provolone"

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const
  myArray = [ {"sandwich": "hamburger", "cheese": "cheddar" }, {"sandwich": "club", "cheese": "provolone" }, {"sandwich": "reuben", "cheese": "swiss" } ],
  sammy = "club";
  
const { cheese } = myArray.find(({ sandwich }) => sandwich === sammy) || {};

console.log(cheese);
```

Comment: Works great! Simple and easy!